# Selecionar o último registro de cada dia e subtrair do dia anterior, mostrando a diferenca

Tags: sql, sql-server

Supomos que tenho a seguinte tabela ENERGIA_UG1:

| E3TimeStamp | ENERGIA_UG1_ATIVA_POSITIVA |
| --- | --- |
| 01/10/2021 00:00 | 0 |
| 01/10/2021 03:00 | 100 |
| 01/10/2021 06:00 | 150 |
| 01/10/2021 12:00 | 300 |
| 01/10/2021 18:00 | 450 |
| 02/10/2021 00:00 | 500 |
| 02/10/2021 03:00 | 600 |
| 02/10/2021 06:00 | 650 |
| 02/10/2021 12:00 | 700 |
| 02/10/2021 18:00 | 850 |
| 03/10/2021 00:00 | 900 |
| 03/10/2021 03:00 | 1000 |
| 03/10/2021 06:00 | 1050 |
| 03/10/2021 12:00 | 2000 |
| 03/10/2021 18:00 | 2450 |

consegui pegar a diferença entre os horários do dia com este código:

```
SELECT ENERGIA_UG1_ATIVA_POSITIVA - LAG(ENERGIA_UG1_ATIVA_POSITIVA,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY E3TimeStamp)

FROM ENERGIA_UG1
```

Answer (score -2):

Segue uma possível solução.

```
USE MASTER 
GO 

;WITH TAB ( [DATAHORA],[VALOR]  )
AS
(
    SELECT [DATAHORA],[VALOR]
    FROM 
    ( VALUES 
         ('2021-10-01T00:00:00',    0)
        ,('2021-10-01T03:00:00',    100)
        ,('2021-10-01T06:00:00',    150)
        ,('2021-10-01T12:00:00',    300)
        ,('2021-10-01T18:00:00',    450)
        ,('2021-10-02T00:00:00',    500)
        ,('2021-10-02T03:00:00',    600)
        ,('2021-10-02T06:00:00',    650)
        ,('2021-10-02T12:00:00',    700)
        ,('2021-10-02T18:00:00',    850)
        ,('2021-10-03T00:00:00',    900)
        ,('2021-10-03T03:00:00',    1000)
        ,('2021-10-03T06:00:00',    1050)
        ,('2021-10-03T12:00:00',    2000)
        ,('2021-10-03T18:00:00',    2450)
    ) AS TAB([DATAHORA],[VALOR])
)
, TAB_1
AS
(
    SELECT 
         CONVERT(DATETIME2,[DATAHORA],101) AS 'DATAHORA'
        ,[VALOR]
        ,CONVERT(DATE,[DATAHORA],101) AS 'DATA'
    FROM TAB
)
, TAB_2
AS
(
    SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.[DATA]) AS 'SEQ'
        ,T1.[DATA]
        ,MAX(T1.[DATAHORA]) AS 'MAX_DATAHORA'
    FROM TAB_1 T1
    GROUP BY [DATA] 
) 
, TAB_3
AS
(
    SELECT 
         [SEQ]
        ,[DATA]
        ,[MAX_DATAHORA]
        ,[VALOR]
    FROM TAB_2 T 
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT VALOR 
        FROM TAB_1 TI
        WHERE TI.[DATAHORA] = T.[MAX_DATAHORA]
    ) TT
)
SELECT 
     T1.[SEQ]   
    ,T1.[DATA]  
    ,T1.[MAX_DATAHORA]
    ,ISNULL(T2.[VALOR_ANTERIOR],0) AS 'VALOR_ANTERIOR'
    ,T1.[VALOR]
    ,(T1.[VALOR]-ISNULL(T2.[VALOR_ANTERIOR],0)) AS 'DIFF'
FROM TAB_3 T1
OUTER APPLY 
( 
    SELECT [VALOR] AS 'VALOR_ANTERIOR'
    FROM TAB_3 T
    WHERE (T1.SEQ - 1) = T.SEQ
) T2
```